# replace NAN or blank with string pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame.
In one of the columns ('Q8') of this data frame, some of the rows are empty. I would like to replace these empty cells with a string ('ss').
I want to do this replacement with a condition. This condition is that if the string in column ('Q7') is ('I am a student') and the cell in this row at column ('Q8') is empty, replace the empty cell of column ('Q8') with 'ss'.

This is the code which I wrote for it:

```
for xx in range(0,len(df['Q8'])):
    if df['Q8'][xx]==np.nan:
       if df['Q7'][xx]=='I am a student':
           df['Q8'][xx].replace('', 'ss', regex=True)
```

but it can not find any np.nan from the first if!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use masking instead:

```
df.loc[(df['Q7'] == 'I am a student') & (df['Q8'].isna()), 'Q8'] = 'ss'
```

You can also use `fillna`:

```
df.loc[df['Q7'] == 'I am a student', 'Q8'] = df.loc[df['Q7'] == 'I am a student', 'Q8'].fillna('ss')
```

Comment: @CFD and note the use of the isna() function for finding missing values, which works across different data types.

Comment: Why should we put 'Q8' at the end of first method?

Comment: @CFD because we need to mask in two dimensions: we want to modify only the cells which belong to rows where `df[Q7]` has the value `'I am a student'` *and* columns where `df[Q8]` is null.

Comment: @CFD also, the proper syntax for using the .loc indexer is: df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer].